# Addressing the reliability of a report

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Assalamualaikum can someone help verify the authenticity of the following narration? :

> ‘No one reaches forty years in Islam except that Allah protects him from madness, leprosy and leucoderma. When he is fifty, Allah makes easy his reckoning. When he reaches sixty, Allah grants him repentance. And when he reaches seventy, Allah loves him and the inhabitants of the heavens love him. And when he reaches eighty, Allah accepts his good deeds and overlooks his sins. When he reaches ninety, Allah forgives his past and future sins, he is named ‘the prisoner of Allah on earth’ and is granted intercession (for forgiveness) for his family.’

References:

Musnad Ahmad, vol.2 pg.89 and vol.3 pg.218

Musnad Bazzar, see Kashful Astar, Hadith: 3587-3589

Kitabuz Zuhd of Imam Bayhaqi, Hadith: 650-652

Hafiz Ibn Hajar Al-‘Asqalani (rahimahullah) has mentioned seven Sahabah that have reported it.

(Ma’rifatul Khisalil Mukaffirah, pg. 89)

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/125797/

Comment: https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/126807/

Comment: In one of the editions of al-Musnad you may find a deeper analysis and link to other versions mentionings of this hadith, made by the commentators.